# seeming simple rpubchem interactive function produces error

Tags: r, pubchem

The following lines of R code produces the errors in italics.  It would seem to be a rpubchem error, unless I'm doing something stupid:

```
    require(rpubchem);
    get.aid.by.cid(614467, type="raw")
```

Output:

```
***Warning messages:
1: In readLines(icon, n = 100) :
  seek on a gzfile connection returned an internal error
2: In readLines(icon, n = 100) :
  seek on a gzfile connection returned an internal error
3: In file.remove(iname) :
  cannot remove file 'C:\Users\bkoch\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSs77GM\abycbdc276782.gz', reason 'Permission denied'***
```

Anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: this is not an error message. it is a warning message, which are different than error messages. An error means your command was not applied successfully. A warning on the other hand suggests the command was executed (but with caveats)

Answer (score 0):

In the folder mentioned by the warning are temporary files creating during your data pull via this package. The file name mentioned by the warning exists but lacks the `.gz` extension, which is probably part of the problem.

I verified this by running your code and inspecting the files. Apparently the  issue is a minor bug and I would suggest to file a bug report on GitHub.

However please note it's only a warning not an error and the function seems to still work.

Comment: Thanks to both for the clarifications.